# How to find the "Saved Pictures" folder in OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

When you save a picture in Windows Phone (browse the web and save a picture from any website), it is automatically saved to a "Saved Pictures" folder (local) and uploaded to a "Saved Pictures" folder in OneDrive.

I'm trying to create an app which is able to save pictures to OneDrive, and I want to save to that folder.

Is there a way to find that folder?
I know some folders (Camera roll, documents, etc.) have friendly names (/me/skydrive/camera_rol, /me/skydrive/my_documents, etc.). Is there some name to this Saved Pictures? Or is it specific to Windows Phone (Windows Phone creates it).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** in case you are wondering, what I'm trying to do is to develop the Chrome extension I suggested in [UserVoice](http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-general/suggestions/6600063-save-image-to-onedrive-extension).

Comment: Is your app on the phone, desktop, or both?

Comment: @RowlandShaw it is a browser extension, currently working on Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new Onedrive API, there is a way to get access to "[special folders](http://onedrive.github.io/README.htm#special-folders)", and there is a undocumented folder named "savedPictures", but it doesn't work.

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/36#issuecomment-90224248) in their bugtracker and they told me would be fixed.

Once it gets fixed, the right way to access the Saved Pictures folder will be to

```
GET /drive/special/savedPictures
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe the "Saved Pictures" folder is accessible via this mechanism, and on top of that here isn't an easy way to find it yourself since it can be moved and renamed by users.

Comment: That is sad. Thanks anyway. I will use the Camera Roll (/me/skydrive/camera_roll) instead.